# Creating Lookup Filter - Insert Field not showing field

Tags: lookup, filters, lookup-filter

I am trying to create a lookup filter from a custom object (FormProduct) to Product on the FormProduct object lookup field and set the criteria on a field on the FormProduct (ProductType__c) but this field is not available.

I have checked that it is visible and available to everyone and is on the layout.

What have I missed here.  I believe I have followed the documented way to create a filter and cannot see any difference in the other fields on the FormProduct object that are available to be selected.

Any and all help greatly appreciated

Comment: I investigated further and discovered that if I add a new field of type Numeric this will be available.  The previous field I was using was a text field.  Not sure if this is relevant.